# Python: See timestamp of article provided by newspaper3k?

Tags: timestamp, python-newspaper

When I do

```
import newspaper
cnn_paper = newspaper.build(news_source_url, memoize_articles=False)
for article in cnn_paper.articles:
    print(article.url)
exit()
```

I get a list of URLs for articles that I can download from `news_source_url` (e.g., `'http://cnn.com'`) using the `newspaper3k` package. Is there any way to get the timestamps for the various articles?

For CNN specificaly, the dates seem to be encoded in the URLs for many of the articles, but I want to get the article timestamps for *any* news source. And I would like to get both date and time, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pull the published dates for the articles using *Newspaper* with the code below. I reformatted the date output, because they had 00:00:00 timestamps.

```
import newspaper
from datetime import datetime

cnn_paper = newspaper.build('http://cnn.com', memoize_articles=False)
for item in cnn_paper.articles:
  article = newspaper.Article(item.url)
  article.download()
  article.parse()
  if article.url and article.publish_date is not None:
    print(article.url)
    publish_date = datetime.strptime(str(article.publish_date), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    print(publish_date)
```

If you need the article exact published dates with the timestamps then you need to obtain those from the articles' URLs. After looking into the code for *Newspaper*, I found a meta tag extractor.

```
import newspaper

cnn_paper = newspaper.build('http://cnn.com', memoize_articles=False)
for item in cnn_paper.articles:
   article = newspaper.Article(item.url)
   article.download()
   article.parse()
   if article.url and article.publish_date is not None:
     article_meta_data = article.meta_data
     article_published_date = sorted({value for (key, value) in article_meta_data.items() if key == 'pubdate'})
     if article_published_date:
        print(article_published_date)
     else:
        print('no published date provided')
```